# How do I remove small grounds when using a french press?

Tags: coffee, grinding, french-press

When I use a french press to brew coffee, there always is some small grounds with the coffee.

I have adjust the grinder to make coarse grounds, but this does not help a lot.

Can I remove these annoying grounds without a filter?

Answer (score 7):

After pressing the coffee I always let it settle a while prior to pouring.  Pour slowly, then let it settle a moment in the cup.  I leave the last of the coffee in the press to avoid most of the sludge.  Some very fine grounds will inevitably make it into the cup -- it is the nature of the beast.

Comment: This, and make sure you press the plunger down nice and slowly to avoid smaller grounds from being forced through the strainer by the pressure.

Comment: You may want to try a different French press too, I've got one which lets through a lot of grounds simply because it's low quality.